# Python: EOFError: EOF when reading a line ошибка

Tags: python

**Задание:**
На вход программе поступают данные, в которых хранятся строки: псевдоним, уникальных идентификатор, номер заказа, разделенные пробелами. Напишите функцию `solve(str_obj)`, которая выводит эту информацию в виде следующего сообщения:

<номер заказа>, <уникальный идентификатор>, <псевдоним>

**Код:**

```
    a= [str(x) for x in input().split()]

    def solve(str_obj):
        print(', '.join(reversed(str_obj)), end='!\n')

    solve(a)
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last): a=input().split()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: А вы из файла данные на вход скрипту подаёте? Подозреваю, что там перевода строки в конце нет.

Comment: Если вы про end='!\n' то я пробовал и без \n и с \n

Comment: Ввод подаётся в input, а пробовали вы в print и совсем не то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант как говорится в лоб:

```py
a = input()
def solve(str_obj):
    d = {}
    for n, i in enumerate(a.split(" ")):
        d[n] = i
    print(d[2], d[1], d[0])
solve(a)
```